# C++ validation loop issues

Tags: c++, validation

I'm pretty new to c++ and am really close to the solution, but I still need some help. My loop works correctly the first time. After that when I enter the car number, it seems to be grabbing some input somewhere and just executes the invalid color on the second pass. Obviously, I'm missing something, but I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

This is just a small snippet of my program, but there lays the problem:

```
while (count < 3)
{
    cout << endl << "Enter car color: blue, red or green in lower case.  ";
    getline(cin, carColor[count]);

    if (!(carColor[count] == "blue" || carColor[count] == "red" || carColor[count] == "green"))
    {
        cout << "That is an invalid color"
            << "The program will exit";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        return 0;
    }


    cout << endl << "Enter car number between 1 and 99: ";
    cin >> carNumber[count];                   // Enter car number
    if (carNumber[count] >99 || carNumber[count] < 1)
    {
        cout << "That is not a correct number"
            << " The program will exit";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "car no is:" << carNumber[count] << "color: " << carColor[count];


    ++count;
//  int lapCount{ 1 };

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: After you enter the car number, it'll put the number followed by a '\n' (endline character) in the buffer. Since you don't clear cin, after the first iteration of the loop, the buffer only has that endline in it. Getline will then read that endline on the next iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `'\n'` character after you press enter in `cin >> carNumber[count];` probably still remains so after you execute the second pass of `getline(cin, carColor[count]);` you get an empty string. One solution is to do this:

```
char c;
cin >> carNumber[count];
cin >> c;
```

But better solution would be just to change:

```
getline(cin, carColor[count]);
```

to:

```
cin >> carColor[count];
```

Comment: OMG!!!  I guess that's what happens when I look at code for 8 hours.  the cin kept giving me errors, mainly because I had << instead of >>.      Thank you so much!  I feel silly!!  Thank you for the additional information.  I will keep it in mind for next project :)